# capture special string between 2 characters in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have been working on a python project while I don't have that much experience so can you tell me please if I have this string : `Synset'dog.n.01'` and I want to extract the string dog only what should I do ?

I mean just to extract any string between `Synset'` and `.n.01'`

Comment: Extract and replace? Because otherwise just search for a string in string and if found use a new variable with the value `dog`.

Comment: I mean just to extract any string between  Synset' and .n.01'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `re` (regex)

```
import re

s = "Synset'dog.n.01'"
result = re.search("Synset'(.*).n.01'", s)
print result.group(1)
```